# Which design pattern for Activity Logging (Audit Trailing)

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, design-patterns, xml-serialization

I have a winform which allows people to edit data from a database, to simplify things assume there is a Customer table in database with 3 fields - Name, City, Country. Through winform(s) people can Add/Edit/Delete customers.

For each of these actions we need to save:

1. What the field names are (Name,City,Country in this case)
2. What the field values were before they were modified
3. What the field values are after they are modified.

If the action is Add or Delete then 2 and 3 will be the same.

I have already implemented this using XMLSerialisation (but not using any of the design patterns) and my XML output looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ActivityItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserID>26</UserID>
  <FormTitle>frmCustomer</FormTitle>
  <Action>Edit</Action>
  <Area>Customers</Area>
  <TrackedActivity>
    <FieldNames>
      <string>Name</string>
      <string>City</string>
      <string>Country</string>
    </FieldNames>
    <PreValues>
      <string>CompA</string>
      <string>London</string>
      <string>UK</string>
    </PreValues>
    <PostValues>
      <string>CompB</string>
      <string>Manchester</string>
      <string>UK</string>
    </PostValues>
  </TrackedActivity>
  <DateTimeStamp>2012-06-15T10:16:18</DateTimeStamp>
</ActivityItem>
```

The solution can handle different areas of the system with different number of fields (i.e the same thing works when you are modifying Products for instance).

My question is, is there a well defined design pattern to deal with this kind of behavior?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do ... produce a couple classes.  There's an "audit log" thing that collects a bunch of "audit record" things.  Each audit record is either an **Edit** or a **Delete**, and contains the record that was changed and the old value of the object if applicable.

Ok, since there will be multiple object types involved (Customer, Product,...), that says to me that these types ought to be  generic.

This brings me to:

```
public class AuditLog<T>
{
    public int UserID   { get; set; }
    public string LastSaved   { get; set;}

    [XmlArrayItem("Entry")]
    public List<AuditRecord<T>> Records;
}

public enum Flavor
{
    Edit,
    Delete
}

public class AuditRecord<T>
{
    public AuditRecord() { Stamp = DateTime.Now; }

    [XmlAttribute("action")]
    public Flavor Action  { get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute("stamp")]
    public DateTime Stamp   { get; set;}

    public T Before;
    public T After; // maybe null
}
```

And then for a class like this

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public string City   { get; set; }
    public String Country   { get; set; }
}
```

... you would get a document like this:

```
<AuditLogOfCustomer>
  <UserID>0</UserID>
  <LastSaved>2012 Jun 16 20:42:53</LastSaved>
  <Records>
    <Entry action="Edit" stamp="2012-06-16T20:42:52.9622344-07:00">
      <Before>
        <Name>Sheldon</Name>
        <City>Ipswich</City>
        <Country>UK</Country>
      </Before>
      <After>
        <Name>Sheldon</Name>
        <City>London</City>
        <Country>UK</Country>
      </After>
    </Entry>
    <Entry action="Delete" stamp="2012-06-16T20:42:52.9642345-07:00">
      <Before>
        <Name>Sheldon</Name>
        <City>London</City>
        <Country>UK</Country>
      </Before>
    </Entry>
  </Records>
</AuditLogOfCustomer>
```

code:
http://pastebin.com/PKiEefnX

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have already got a similar code, what I am looking for is trying to utilise one of the design patterns (which may or may not be possible)..

Answer (score 1):

I havent heard of a specific design-pattern doing what what you descibed here yet, but i would call it an **Offline updatable Database Snapshot**.

If i read your description correctly you describe what the **[dotnet dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** is doing since dotnet 1.0 and is still working with vs2010/dotnet 4.0 but not promoted by microsoft any more.

- you have a datatable for every object type (in your example Customer)
- you have datarows with fields (Name, City, Country)
- there are different row version (original, actual)
- you can (de) serialize it to xml (WriteXml, LoadXml, GetXml)

What is missing in your description is a **rowstate** that can be used to indicate deleted rows.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you might be right may be there is not a specific design pattern doing what I want.